# Работа OpenDialog в цикле

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe2

**Как обработать несколько файлов открыв их через OpenDialog. Добавила в код:**

```
OpenDialog1.Options := OpenDialog1.Options + [ofAllowMultiSelect];
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
```

**И после:**

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  x: byte = 16;
  bufsize = 1024;
var
  f1, f2: File;
  buf: array [1 .. bufsize] of byte;
  i, count: integer;
begin
 OpenDialog1.Options := OpenDialog1.Options + [ofAllowMultiSelect]; // Выбор несколько файлов...
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
  assignfile(f1, 'in.txt'); ///////////////// Вот тут понимаю что нужно в цикле но как?
  assignfile(f2, 'out.txt');//////////////// Вот тут понимаю что нужно в цикле но как?
  reset(f1, 1);
  rewrite(f2, 1);
  while not eof(f1) do
  begin
    BlockRead(f1, buf, bufsize, count);
    for i := 1 to count do
      buf[i] := buf[i] xor x;
    BlockWrite(f2, buf, count);
  end;
  closefile(f1);
  closefile(f2);
end;
end;
```

**Теперь что нужно прописать вот тут:**

```
 assignfile(f1, 'in.txt'); // Входящий файл
 assignfile(f2, 'out.txt'); // исходящий
```

Предполагаю что в цикле или массиве ?, как правильно будет ? Или может:

```
If OpenDialog1.Execute Then
For i := 0 to OpenDialog1.Files.Count-1 do
begin
CurrentFile := OpenDialog1.Files.Strings[i];

Где  CurrentFile: array of string; /////////////////
```

Не пойму как правильно ?.

Comment: В цикле имена файлов можно получить вот так: `OpenDialog1.Files[i]`. Но логика у вас в коде странная. Должно быть 2 диалога: первый для выбора входного файла, а второй для выбора выходного. Иначе у вас будет каша.

Comment: @zed, Я на самом деле хочу что сделать: Через OpenDialog ,выбираю два или три нужных файла и код обрабатывает их и сохраняет с именами out1.txt + out2.txt + out3.txt. Но не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    for i := 0 to OpenDialog1.Files.Count - 1 do
    begin
      AssignFile(f1, OpenDialog1.Files[i]);
      AssignFile(f2, 'out' + IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt');
      Reset(f1, 1);
      Rewrite(f2, 1);
      ...
      CloseFile(f1);
      CloseFile(f2);
    end;
  end;
```